# Where can I find dataset for word analogy task?

Tags: nlp, dataset, word2vec

In the paper of Word2Vec by Thomas Mikolov and others, there is a accuracy report on the full Semantic-Syntactic data set. Where I can find this dataset or a related dataset for word analogy task?

Here is the paper link and I'm referring to table 5. 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want a word analogy dataset for the english language to test your word embeddings. Check the following link where you can find Mikolov's dataset [Word Analogy Dataset](https://github.com/nicholas-leonard/word2vec/blob/master/questions-words.txt).

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want a long text file of some sort that can easily be analysed. I would suggest that you use project [Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org) which publishes thousands of free to use books in plain UTF-8 text format. For example here is [Pride and Prejudice by Jane Austin](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1342/1342-0.txt).